# Samsung Galaxy A51, please enter your PIN code. AGAIN?

Tags: samsung, lock-screens

From my employer, I've received a smartphone Samsung Galaxy A51. Almost at everything I want to do with it, I need to enter my PIN code. I would like to use my smartphone without needing to enter my PIN code again and again and again and again ...

In my own smartphone, also a Samsung, but a Samsung Galaxy A6+, there I don't need to enter my PIN code that much.

I've been looking in the settings, but I don't find where to modify that configuration.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: It is likely flashed with a proprietary OS version for their protection. If it is their property they can likely enforce any security they deem required to protect their property. Remember they are tracking EVERYTHING you do on their phone.

Comment: If the comapany you work for has an IT department ask them. If it can't be done they will tell you.

Comment: Could you explain further by "enter my PIN code again and again"? I'd assume this is when the device wakes up from sleep/screen turns off? Or are there other situations when it asks again? If it's the former, then it's probably set by the IT admin, which can be enforced by Android Device Policy as the device administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Fingerprint?
Face unlock?
If you have a fingerprint use it.
If not then use face unlock.
Fingerprint is more secure than face unlock.

Comment: I would like to avoid these: I mean, if I don't need to enter my pincode on my Samsung Galaxy a6+, then it should be possible on my Samsung A51 too, or not?

Comment: @Dominique Well, it's a safety measure. Look into your apps's settings for an option to disable them.
If not then you have 2 choices:
Removing your pin
or using fingerprint or face unlock